# How to convert / evaluate an expression into a variable

Tags: c++

If have a string:

```
std::string a = "{0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0}";
```

How can I convert it to so b is (double*)a ? something like:

```
double *b = {0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
```

I am looking for some function that provides that literal evaluation instead of loop through the contents of the string, etc.

Comment: You should look into serialization. For example, there are libraries that can serialize/unserialize data from the json format

Comment: Use a library such as [cereal](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/).

Comment: There is no standard mechanism for this. Strings cannot be automatically interpreted as code during runtime. You would need to somehow compile it at runtime and integrate it with your executable, which is a very advanced and potentially dangerous technique. The concept of code pretty much disappears at run time (except maybe for debugging). You'll need to parse the string yourself or find a library that already does it the way you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no built-in `eval()` equivalent in C++. There are many reasons for this, but the simplest is that C++ is a compiled language. So the code is parsed by the compiler and not the run-time. In order to add an `eval()`-like function, the parser would also need to be included in the run-time, which would greatly increase its size.

If you actually need to parse valid C++ expressions, there are libraries you can use to do that.

Comment: [`cling`](https://github.com/root-project/cling) is for example an interactive c++ interpreter.